# JQuery Iterate through JSON and print into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

I have a JSON list, which can have an array of "OrderLines" , within this array is other data such as part number, price etc...

I want to be able to print/display each "OrderLine" and its data in some HTML elements/tags, for each order-line the HTML elements are to be repeated, meaning I don't want e.g. all Part-Numbers to be in the SAME div tag, hopefully the code below will make sense as to what I want to achieve

```
    {
        "Depot": 4,
        "DocumentType": "Sales Order",
        "DocumentNumber": "123",
        "OrderDate": "2022-06-23T09:09:12+01:00",
        "OrderReference": "TEST",
        "OrderedBy": "",
        "ContactName": "",
        "AccountCode": "EXAMPLE",
        "CustomerName": "EXAMPLE",
        "CustomerAddress1": "EXAMPLE",
        "CustomerAddress2": "EXAMPLE",
        "CustomerAddress3": "EXAMPLE",
        "CustomerAddress4": "EXAMPLE",
        "DepotVATNumber": "GB EXAMPLE",
        "DeliveryName": "EXAMPLE",
        "DeliveryAddress1": "EXAMPLE",
        "DeliveryAddress2": "EXAMPLE",
        "DeliveryAddress3": "EXAMPLE",
        "DeliveryAddress4": "EXAMPLE",
        "OrderLines": [
            {
                "PartNumber": "EXAMPLE",
                "Description": "EXAMPLE",
                "IncludeCostCodes": false,
                "MaterialCode": "0",
                "CostCentre": "",
                "Quantity": 2,
                "Price": 9.5,
                "TotalAmount": 19,
                "VATRate": 20
            }
{
                "PartNumber": "EXAMPLE 2",
                "Description": "EXAMPLE 2",
                "IncludeCostCodes": false,
                "MaterialCode": "0",
                "CostCentre": "",
                "Quantity": 0,
                "Price": 0,
                "TotalAmount": 0,
                "VATRate": 0
            }
        ],
        "TotalGoods": 19,
        "TotalVat": 3.8,
        "GrandTotal": 22.8
    }
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
    let order = @Html.Raw(Model.Content);
    $('.billaddN').text(order.CustomerName + "," );
    $('.billadd1').text(order.CustomerAddress1 + "," );
    $('.billadd2').text(order.CustomerAddress2 + "," );
    $('.billadd3').text(order.CustomerAddress3 + "," );
    $('.billadd4').text(order.CustomerAddress4);
    $('.shippadd1').text(order.DeliveryAddress1 + "," );
    $('.shippadd2').text(order.DeliveryAddress2 + "," );
    $('.shippadd3').text(order.DeliveryAddress3 + "," );
    $('.shippadd4').text(order.DeliveryAddress4);
    $('.shippaddN').text(order.DeliveryName + "," );
    $('.ordRef').text(order.OrderReference);
    $('.ordNo').text(order.DocumentNumber);
    $('.ordDate').text(order.OrderDate);
    $('.ordBy').text(order.OrderedBy);
    $('.subtotal').text("£" + order.TotalGoods);
    $('.totalvat').text("£" + order.TotalVat);
    $('.total').text("£" + order.GrandTotal);
    $('.vatNo').text(order.DepotVATNumber);
    $('.accountNo').text(order.AccountCode);

    
    $(order.OrderLines).each(function(i,e) {
                                    $(".order-lines-container").append(
                                            '<tr>
                                                <td width="80%">
                                                <span class="font-weight-bold">order.PartNumber[i]</span>
                                                <div class="product-qty">
                                                    <span class="d-block">order.Description[i]</span>
                                                    <span>Color</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="20%">
                                                <div class="text-right">
                                                    <span class="font-weight-bold">order.Price[i]</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>'
                                
                                    )});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost there, the issue you have is that your `each()` loop doesn't reference the specific line in the array you're iterating through.

In addition, the looping code can be simplified and made more performant by using `map()` to create an array of strings which you then append to the DOM just once.

Here's a working example:

```js
var order = {Depot:4,DocumentType:"Sales Order",DocumentNumber:"123",OrderDate:"2022-06-23T09:09:12+01:00",OrderReference:"TEST",OrderedBy:"",ContactName:"",AccountCode:"EXAMPLE",CustomerName:"EXAMPLE",CustomerAddress1:"EXAMPLE",CustomerAddress2:"EXAMPLE",CustomerAddress3:"EXAMPLE",CustomerAddress4:"EXAMPLE",DepotVATNumber:"GB EXAMPLE",DeliveryName:"EXAMPLE",DeliveryAddress1:"EXAMPLE",DeliveryAddress2:"EXAMPLE",DeliveryAddress3:"EXAMPLE",DeliveryAddress4:"EXAMPLE",OrderLines:[{PartNumber:"EXAMPLE",Description:"EXAMPLE",IncludeCostCodes:!1,MaterialCode:"0",CostCentre:"",Quantity:2,Price:9.5,TotalAmount:19,VATRate:20},{PartNumber:"EXAMPLE 2",Description:"EXAMPLE 2",IncludeCostCodes:!1,MaterialCode:"0",CostCentre:"",Quantity:0,Price:0,TotalAmount:0,VATRate:0}],TotalGoods:19,TotalVat:3.8,GrandTotal:22.8}

let rows = order.OrderLines.map(line => `
  <tr>
      <td width="80%">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">${line.PartNumber}</span>
        <div class="product-qty">
          <span class="d-block">${line.Description}</span>
          <span>Color</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="20%">
      <div class="text-right">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">${line.Price}</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>`);
  
$(".order-lines-container").append(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="order-lines-container"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, appreciate your support :), only issue i have noticed is that the <td> elements that "width..." is no longer being applied , any idea why this may have happened?

Comment: Most likely because the `width` attribute is outdated and may not be applied (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-width), use CSS instead.

Comment: Solved, i appended the <tbody> instead , having a div after <tbody> for some reason made the rows not be printed within the tobdy tag...simple fix, thanks again

Comment: Ah I see, you can't have a `div` as a child of a table or tbody element, so that's most likely the cause. Glad you got it working.